When is $L=I\omega$ not valid and why?
I was reading about that angular momentum $L=I\omega$ is not valid when the body is not symmetrical why so? We can still find the m.o.i. By integration so why the condition?


Where do you read that? A little of context would help to answer faster.

The relation you wrote is a special "high-school" case of a most general formula, that holds if you're referring the angular momentum to the center of mass, $G$
$$L_G = I_G \, \omega \ ,$$
regardless of everything else.
Rotational dynamics. In 3D space, rotational dynamics becomes a little subtle, and you need to know a bit of vector and tensor algebra: angular momentum $\mathbf{L}_G$ and angular velocity $\boldsymbol{\omega}$ are vector quantities, while the properties of the body relevant for the rotational dynamics are represented by inertia tensor $\mathbb{I}_G$ and the relation reads
$$\mathbf{L}_G = \mathbb{I}_G \cdot \boldsymbol{\omega} \ .$$
"High-school rotational dynamics". In order to avoid tensors, we need to limit ourselves to study rotations in a prescribed direction, or around axis with constant direction. Even in this case, the relation you wrote only holds if we're using COM as the reference point for $L_G$ and $I_G$. If you want/need to use other reference points, you need to use rigid body motion to transport momentum and inertia, see Huygens transport theorem.
Changing the reference point from $G$ to $P$, the angular momentum w.r.t. $P$ for the "high-school rotational dynamics" is
$$L_P = L_G + \hat{\mathbf{z}} \cdot (\mathbf{r}_G-\mathbf{r}_P) \times \mathbf{Q} = L_G + m|\mathbf{r}_G - \mathbf{r}_P||\mathbf{v}_G| \sin \theta \ ,$$
being $\mathbf{Q} = m \mathbf{v}_G$ the momentum of the rigid body, $m$ its total mass and $\mathbf{v}_G$.
The rule for inertia gives you $I_G = I_P - m|\mathbf{r}_P - \mathbf{r}_Q|^2$, following Huygens transport theorem.
Replacing the expression of $L_G$ and $I_G$ in the expression above, it should be clear that the formula becomes more complex, and other terms appear, containing the momentum of the body and the position of the pole $P$ w.r.t. the COM, something like
$$L_P - m|\mathbf{r}_G - \mathbf{r}_P||\mathbf{v}_G| \sin \theta = (I_P - m|\mathbf{r}_P - \mathbf{r}_Q|^2) \omega$$
or
$$L_P = I_P \omega + m|\mathbf{r}_G - \mathbf{r}_P| \left( |\mathbf{r}_G-\mathbf{r}_P| \omega + |\mathbf{v}_G | \sin \theta \right)$$

The formula angular momentum $L= I\omega$ is valid for planar figures, and it can be used also for symmetrical bodies. In all these cases, angular momentum is parallel to the axis of rotation. However, in the general case, the relation between rotation and angular momentum is a linear mapping between 3D vectors. We still have something like angular momentum $\mathbf{L}= I\boldsymbol{\omega}$, but angular momentum $\mathbf{L}$ and $\boldsymbol{\omega}$ are both 3D vectors, and $I$ is a tensor - the inertia tensor.
The difference with the planar or symmetrical case is that rotating around $x$-axis yields an angular momentum in the direction of $x$-axis, but it may also yield an angular momentum in the direction of axes $y$ and $z$. Hence the need for an inertia matrix.
To grasp the - quite counterintuitive - idea of a rotation around one axis yielding angular momentum with components on perpendicular axis, please consider this sketch:

We have two equal point masses rotating around the $x$-axis, but they are not symmetrical around the $x$-axis. You can see that they produce an angular momentum around $x$-axis, but they also produce an angular momentum around $z$-axis. Therefore, to describe angular momentum we need its $x$ component but also its other components.
How to compute the three components of angular momentum from the three components of $\omega$ may be a bit complex for your present level, but to get an idea about how it works, you can imagine the inertia tensor $I$ as an structure of 9 numbers in a square that can be multiplied by a vector (rotation) and the result is another vector (angular momentum).
Anyway, as you said, "We can still find the m.o.i. By integration so why the condition?", however, you will only get the moment of inertia around the rotation axis, and it will be useful to compute one component of angular momentum - that m.o.i. will be just one component of the inertia matrix - and you will be ignoring the other components of angular momentum.

"...I is a tensor"

Fixed. It's a tensor because we get a different matrix for every reference frame, although I'm not sure fixing that in the answer is helpful at understanding it, according to the level of the question.

agree with you. Not sure about the level of proficiency the OP. Hard to tune the level of the answers

I am actually in 12th grade high school so I am not quite familiar with the rules of tensor quantities but I am familiar with vector algebra and 3d geometry basics do u think you could dumb down the explanation haha what I understood from your explanation was that if the axis is x the L could exist for y and z too and hence the angular momentum L isn’t total angular momentum it is just about that particular axis, is that what u are saying? If yes I am sorry how could they have angular momentum about any other axis? The rotation is about one particular axis. Forgive me for being new to this :,)

@Pere Why do you say the equation is only valid for "planar figures"?

@ReetSaini - Please see whether my sketchy drawing and explanation helps.

@BobD - Again I'm trying to simplify as much as I can. The 1D equation is valid for planar figures rotating around an axis perpendicular to the plane that contains such planar figures, and other cases symmetrical enough. We could be a lot more precise, but I'm afraid it won't help the OP to understand the answer.

@BobD thanks a lot for the help it sort of makes sense now I was having trouble with this before

@ReetSaini See my answer just posted.

@ReetSaini Bob D looks a good answer to me. Does it look good to you as well? In order to avoid tensors, we need to limit ourselves to study rotations in a prescribed direction, or around axis with constant direction. Even in this case, the relation you wrote only holds if we're using COM as the reference point for $L_G$ and $I_G$. If you want/need to use other reference points, you need to use rigid body motion to transport momentum and inertia, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_axis_theorem

@BobD I am so sorry I don’t understand  do you think you could see what I edited in the post and see what exactly is going on? I studied this topic in 11th and looking back I have realised my conceptual clarity is in the gutter I am so sorry for the trouble

@basics yes that whole parallel axis theorem application to get new m.o.i. Then new L = Iw is valid but i just read a question and my notes from a book that i have attached to my post now that caused this confusion

Without seeing the full context of what you read, I can only guess they are referring to the case where $I$ is the moment of inertia about an axis through the center of mass (COM)
$$L=I_{com}\omega$$
and that $I_{com}$ can be different depending on which axis through the COM is chosen.
For example, in the figure below taken from the Hyperphysics website the moment of inertia about the COM of the solid cylinder and hoop depends on whether or not it is the symmetry axis. On the other hand, for the solid sphere, the moment of inertia is the same about any axis through the COM.
Hope this helps.


If mass moment of inertia $I$ is a scalar value then it only applies for rotationally symmetric objects (like a sphere).
The proper definition uses $${\rm I} = \pmatrix{ I_{xx} & I_{xy} & I_{xz} \\ I_{xy} & I_{yy} & I_{yz} \\ I_{xz} & I_{yz} & I_{zz} }$$ a 2nd order tensor that converts the 3D vector of angular velocity to the 3D vector of angular momentum.
In expanded form then the general formula is
$$ \pmatrix{L_x \\ L_y \\ L_z}  = \pmatrix{ I_{xx} & I_{xy} & I_{xz} \\ I_{xy} & I_{yy} & I_{yz} \\ I_{xz} & I_{yz} & I_{zz} } \pmatrix{\omega_x \\ \omega_y \\ \omega_z} $$
if the basis vectors (elementary directions) are along the principal axes of the body then the above is only a diagonal matrix
$$ \pmatrix{L_x \\ L_y \\ L_z}  = \pmatrix{ I_{X} &  &  \\  & I_{Y} &  \\  &  & I_{Z} } \pmatrix{\omega_x \\ \omega_y \\ \omega_z} $$
Furthermore, if the body has full symmetry, then all principal MMOI values are the same $I = I_X = I_Y = I_Z$ and this makes the above formula you stated as follows (with $I$ a scalar MMOI value)
$$ \pmatrix{L_x \\ L_y \\ L_z}  = \pmatrix{ I &  &  \\  & I &  \\  &  & I } \pmatrix{\omega_x \\ \omega_y \\ \omega_z} = I \pmatrix{\omega_x \\ \omega_y \\ \omega_z} $$

If a solid body contains all particles with mass $m_i$ and coordinates $\boldsymbol{r}_i = \pmatrix{x_i\\y_i\\z_i}$ then the mass moment of inertia tensor is defined by
$$ {\rm I} = \sum_i m_i \pmatrix{ 
y_i^2+z_i^2  & -x_i y_i & -x_i z_i \\
-x_i y_i & x_i^2+z_i^2 & -y_i z_i \\
-x_I z_i & y_i z_i & x_i^2+y_i^2} $$
This is the expansion of a more formal definition of
$$ {\rm I} = \sum_i m_i \left( \boldsymbol{r}_i \cdot \boldsymbol{r}_i - \boldsymbol{r}_i \odot \boldsymbol{r}_i \right) $$
where $\cdot$ is the inner product, and $\odot$ the outer product.
I am not going to show the derivation of the above, but it is fairly straightforward to derive from the velocity of each particle $\boldsymbol{v}_i = \boldsymbol{\omega} \times \boldsymbol{r}_i$ and the angular momentum about the origin $\boldsymbol{L}_i = \boldsymbol{r}_i \times \boldsymbol{p}_i = \boldsymbol{r}_i \times (m_i \boldsymbol{v}_i)$ and the vector triple product $\boldsymbol{a}\times ( \boldsymbol{b} \times \boldsymbol{c}) = \boldsymbol{b} ( \boldsymbol{a}^\intercal \boldsymbol{c}) - \boldsymbol{c} ( \boldsymbol{a}^\intercal \boldsymbol{b})$
